# JMonkey, model not visible

Tags: jmonkeyengine

Why isn't my model visible in the scene?
I'm working through the JMonkey tutorial and trying to use a .j3o model I loaded. When I double click the model in the file manager, it opens in an editor window and is visible when I turn on the light. When I replace the "Ninja" model in the tutorial with my model, the scene appears to compile and run OK, but my model is not visible. The model appears grey and white in the editor. I used Sketchup to build the model. I didn't add any textures or materials to the model in sketchup. Materials, MatDefs and Textures directories are all empty. I remmed out the code for the wall and the teapot. The scene appears blank

```
        // Load a model from test_data (OgreXML + material + texture)
    Spatial rotor1 = assetManager.loadModel("Models/Rotor1/Rotor1.mesh.j3o");
    rotor1.scale(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f);
    rotor1.rotate(0.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f);
    rotor1.setLocalTranslation(0.0f, -5.0f, -2.0f);
    rootNode.attachChild(rotor1);
    // You must add a light to make the model visible
    DirectionalLight sun = new DirectionalLight();
    sun.setDirection(new Vector3f(-0.1f, -0.7f, -1.0f));
    rootNode.addLight(sun);
```

Comment: I went back into Sketchup and added textures to the model, exported/imported it with a new name. Just as with the first model, it appears fine in the editor when I double click it and turn on the light, but does not appear in the scene. So any help will be appreciated.

Comment: OK, I got it figured out:
My model was about 1/100th the size of the Ninja, and it was built with the origin at it's center. So it was there, just very small and off the screen at the bottom. Apparently the Ninja is built with the origin at the bottom. I just had to adjust the Scaling and LocalTranslation.

Comment: You figured it out? Then I suggest you to repost that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When exported make sure everything from blender or similar tools is packed to your export file as a complete copy and not just a link.

It could also be everything worked but you scaled your model down 5000 times its original size. I recomend you try importing it 1:1 first:

```
 rotor1.scale(1f, 1f, 1f);
```